# Java on Windows 7

Tags: java, installation

I've installed java(jre) on window 7. But I am not able to run java from command prompt .

I've set my JRE_HOME to "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6 " in Environment variables.But still it's not working.kindly help..

Comment: Try setting `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: If you do Java -version in console, what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, that the `bin` folder of your JRE is added to the `PATH` variable. `JAVA_HOME` is irrelevant here.

`JAVA_HOME` is a convention - some tools use that environment variable to pick the location of the *right* java version. They use it to construct a path like this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version
```

(that should work, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Add the location of the `bin` directory to the front of your PATH environment variable.

The simplest way to get a default Java is to go to http://java.com and let it install what it feels like.  This will be available in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command at cmd (assuming java is installed at "C:\Program Files\Java" and version is 1.6.0):

```
set path=;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\";
```